# ¿Cómo aplicar formato de fecha a un input de tipo date en html 5?

Tags: php, html5, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con las fechas. Cuando obtengo un valor de tipo date de BBDD, lo muestro en el value de un input de type='date' no muestra la fecha, solo muestra dd/mm/aaaa.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
<label for="inputBirthday" class="control-label">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
<input name='birthday' type="date" class="form-control" id="birthday" value="<?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION["birthday_patient"])) {
        echo $_SESSION["birthday_patient"];
    }?>" required>
```

Esta imagen hace referencia al input de tipo fecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, si pongo el input de tipo text, muestra correctamente la fecha pero cuando se va a editar no aparece el calendario de BootStrap.

¿Alguien sabe qué puede ser? He probado formatear la fecha en el value pero no hay manera.

Comment: El problema no tiene nada que ver con PHP - cuando usas un `<input type="date" />` el formato de la fecha está controlado por el navegador. Si lo quieres cambiar, tendrás que usar `type="text"` y JavaScript.

Comment: Consultas para tener más antecedentes: Cuando el text muestra la fecha ¿en qué formato la muestra?  ¿ 01/02/1980? o ¿ 1980/02/01? en qué formato tienes la fecha en la BBDD

Comment: Pon `echo $_SESSION["birthday_patient"];` también fuera del input y enséñanos qué se muestra en ese caso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lamentablemente HTML5 no proporciona una manera de especificar un atributo de formato de fecha, sólo la especificación [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) de fecha válida como `2011-09-29`.

Es por esto que debes colocar el formato `ISO Y-m-d` en tu PHP para que la fecha se muestre correcta:

```
value="<?PHP  echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($usr->__GET('Fecha'))); ?>
```

o en tu caso específico

```
if(isset($_SESSION["birthday_patient"])) {
   $fecha = $_SESSION["birthday_patient"];
}  
value="<?PHP  echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($fecha )); ?>
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ojo que el uso de este Input aun no es compatible con todos los navegadores. Un alternativa viable es usar un [Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) de JQuery.

[Referencia 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

[Referencia 2](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/hTcMLVNKnec)

Comment: Al final ha quedado así:

`<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
 <label for="inputBirthday" class="control-label">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
 <input name='birthday' type="date" class="form-control" id="birthday" value="<?php 
  if(isset($_SESSION["birthday_patient"])) {
   echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_SESSION["birthday_patient"])); 
  }?>" required disabled>
</div>`

Revisaré temas de compatibilidades o pensaré la otra alternativa conjQuery, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

El `<input type="date">` no depende de PHP sino de HTML5, que no es totalmente compatible con todos los navegadores. Lo mejor sería usar alguna solución en JavaScript para mostrar el datepicker.

El datepicker de jQuery es una buena alternativa, pero ya que estás usando Bootstrap quizás te convenga usar algún datepicker hecho para Bootstrap, como este (que es el que yo uso):

[Datepicker en Bootstrap](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

hola mira este ejemplo:

[Date input HTML5](http://www.anerbarrena.com/date-input-html5-2829/)

mira que la parte importante es el value:

value="2016-02-16" --> asignado manual o

value= echo date("Y-m-d"); // esta parte la inserta como php