# formato de fecha HTML

Tags: java, html5, spring

¿Cómo puedo cambiar esto  . *&total=10&**fecha=2018-03-02**&idAgR=1* .  a 
  *&total=10&**fecha=201/03/02**&idAgR=1* . ?  ya que hago una peticion directa ya sea Chrome o Firefox [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya que me marca un error en este método

> public String RegGiro(Remitente rm, Recividor rc, Items it, int idAgR, Giro gr) {...}

con lo cual debo cambiar esto `2018-03-02` a `2018/03/02` en la URL

```
public class Items implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer idItem;
private BigDecimal monto;
private BigDecimal igv;
private BigDecimal total;
private BigDecimal comision;
private Date fecha;
```

}

Comment: Para los datepicker que ocupas? el control por defecto de HTML5? o algo así o utilizar datepicker de alguna libreria?

Comment: del navegador, o por defecto de HTML5

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta, en tu caso es utilizar javascript dado las razones expuestas en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4263/c%C3%B3mo-aplicar-formato-de-fecha-a-un-input-de-tipo-date-en-html-5